# SpringBoot Accessing H2 console

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a basic SpringBoot app., embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine. I've created this bean to access the console:

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean h2ConsoleServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
    bean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
    return bean;
}
```

I access to the console: `http://localhost:8080/appContext/console/login.do?jsessionid=f3585792a9bf1f0cf1a0b6a09dcefe1a`

I have my beans annotated as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
..
}
```

My application properties:

```
# Spring Data JPA properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

But I don't see any table created by JPA:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove all you have in your properties file. All of those you mentioned are default. Spring-boot will configure it any way as soon as it identifies h2 dependency in your pom. And also you don't need that `ServletRegistration` bean. Remove that as well. Just put this in your properties file
`spring.h2.console.enabled=true`.

By default console can be accessed on `http://localhost:8080/h2-console`, default path is `h2-console`. You can configure it using `spring.h2.console.path` property.

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran , Can we use a similar kind of setup for mysql as well ?

Comment: Yes of course. But remember springboot assumes lot of stuff when it does autoconfiguration. So if springboot's assumption doesnt match with ur setup, it doesn't work. Then you might have to add entries in properties file

Answer (score 8):

We only need below configuration in `application.properties` file:

```ini
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

By default h2 will be available at `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/`

But one can define `spring.h2.console.path=/h2` in `application.properties` and after that h2 can be accessed using `http://localhost:8080/h2`.

Now if you have implemented `SecurityConfig` in application then you will need to add

```
// Make H2-Console non-secured; for debug purposes
.and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2/**")
// Allow pages to be loaded in frames from
// the same origin; needed for H2-Console
.and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
```

in `http.authorizeRequests()`

Comment: you my friend are GOD sent . thank you & God Bless !

Answer (score 6):

We can access the H2 console with default path as `http://localhost:8080/h2-console` if we have devtools dependency in pom.xml else we have to specify the path for H2 in an application.properties as below

---

***With devtools*** can be accessed at `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/`

*POM: spring-boot-starter, h2, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-devtools*

***Without devtools*** - we need to set it in properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true 
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

*POM: spring-boot-starter, h2, spring-boot-starter-web*

<sup>This was the case for Spring Boot 2.1.1 might helpful to others</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not have to explicitly define a bean to access H2 Console. It is taken care by the Springboot already. You can define the H2 Console path in your application.properties like below:

```
spring.h2.path = /h2-console
```

You can access the console via

```
http://host:port/h2-console
```

Secondly, Always use the ddl-auto property as "update" rather than "create" because create will delete existing schema.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

If you're looking for a starter project of Spring boot and H2 (with Hiberante Enver as bonus, remove the enver package and @Audited from the entity if you do not want that) -  You can try the below one:

https://github.com/sundarsy/springboot-h2-enver

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Try setting this property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: same result :-(

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is to let Spring Boot to create the schema for us based on entity/model on the startup. It has nothing to do with H2