# Cant connect with H2 in memory DB. cant see the reason why

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, h2

Is anyone using H2 in memory database? I want to use it in combination with springboot, only when I go to the link of the database I apparently get another login screen. As far as I know nothing is running on port 8080. I also disabled the spring security dependency just to be sure.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

[and the login screen i get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9eUr.png)

---

[In the photo you see my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9eUr.png)

Comment: Looks like spring security is still enabled.

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952259/springboot-accessing-h2-console